# Suppress git warning about default initial branch name

Tags: git

When creating a new Git repo you now see this message:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/var/folders/g5/8twmk1xj481_6btvppyw5j4h0000gp/T/.tmpNYVg6H/.git/
hint: Using 'master' as the name for the initial branch. This default branch name
hint: is subject to change. To configure the initial branch name to use in all
hint: of your new repositories, which will suppress this warning, call:
hint: 
hint:   git config --global init.defaultBranch <name>
hint: 
hint: Names commonly chosen instead of 'master' are 'main', 'trunk' and
hint: 'development'. The just-created branch can be renamed via this command:
hint: 
hint:   git branch -m <name>
```

Is there a way to suppress this message *without* changing my global git config?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like you can do

```
git init --quiet   # or git init -q
```

I'm not exactly sure what other information that will suppress but it suppresses this notice.

However it does mean that the initial branch name is not well defined (they might change it to e.g. `main` later), so it's probably best to do this:

```
git init --initial-branch=master    # or git init -b master
```

Comment: Rather than explicitly setting the `--initial-branch` every time you `git init`, why not... set the `init.defaultBranch` configuration?

Comment: This is for some tests involving git. I don't want them to rely on my global git config.

Comment: This is perfect, I don't want to change it on my global setting and affect all repositories.

Answer (score 5):

This will suppress the *initial branch warning* message for the current user:

```
git config --global init.defaultBranch master
```

This will suppress it system-wide:

```
sudo git config --system init.defaultbranch master
```

*Credit to comments by [Timmmm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66483436/suppress-git-warning-about-default-initial-branch-name#comment117532727_66483477) & [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe)*